# Finding Secondary Tiles in my Background Task fails with code 1

Tags: c#, windows-8, background, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I want to update my Secondary Tiles via a Background Task. My problem is, that iterating through all pinned tiles with `SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync();` fails and exits my Background Task with code 1.

I have no idea, why it is not possible to do that, why I don't get any exceptions and why this works within the main app. Could this be a memory problem?

My code looks like this:

```
public sealed class SecondaryTileUpdater : IBackgroundTask
{
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        var list = await SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync(); // Here it fails :(
        foreach (SecondaryTile liveTile in list)
        {
            // Update Secondary Tiles
            // (...)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error I get:

```
The program '[5644] backgroundTaskHost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

Any ideas, what could be reasons for this?
Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once your async method awaits, your task is ending.  Request a deferral to give your asynchronous code time to execute.

```
public sealed class SecondaryTileUpdater : IBackgroundTask
{
    public async void Run(IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance)
    {
        //HERE: request a deferral
        var deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

        var list = await SecondaryTile.FindAllAsync(); // Here it fails :(
        foreach (SecondaryTile liveTile in list)
        {
            // Update Secondary Tiles
            // (...)
        }

        //HERE: indicate you are done with your async operations
        deferral.Complete();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works absolutelety great for me. Thank you very much!